# jQuery Mobile/ WebSQL database doesn't display until page refresh

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to load and display a WebSQL database within my application, after parsing some xml data into it. The problem is the database is displayed only after I reload the application. Is there any method that I can use to display it at 1st launch?

Here is the code I use for displaying the database entries:

```
 <script>


        var db;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            createDatabaseAndPopulateRecords();
            loadEventRecords();

            $(document).on("click", "#aEventRecord", function () {
                console.log('You just tapped on record number : ' + $(this).data('key'));
                getEventById($(this).data("key"));
            });

        });


        function createDatabaseAndPopulateRecords() {
            //set-up database name
            console.log('Creating database...');
            db = openDatabase('events', '1.0', 'eventsDatabase', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
            db.transaction(function (tx) {

                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (id UNIQUE, name, location, date, descr, img)');
            });

            parseXMLtoDB();

        }


        function parseXMLtoDB() {

            $.get('eventsdata.xml', function (xml) {

                $(xml).find("event").each(function () {

                    var id, name, location, date, descr, img;

                    id = $(this).find("id").text();
                    name = $(this).find("name").text();
                    location = $(this).find("location").text();
                    date = $(this).find("date").text();
                    descr = $(this).find("description").text();
                    img = $(this).find("img").text();

                    db.transaction(function (tx) {
                        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO events (id, name, location, date, descr, img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', [id, name, location, date, descr, img]);
                    });

                    console.log(id, name, location, date);

                });

            });

        }


        function loadEventRecords() {
            console.log('Loading events records from database into #listofevents ul...');
            db.transaction(function (txs) {
                txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM events', [], function (txs, results) {
                    var len = results.rows.length, i;
                    //loop around each event record in the database
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var EventRecord = results.rows.item(i);

                        //create event list item list item. 
                        var individualEvent = '';
                        individualEvent = '<li><a href="#detailinfo" id="aEventRecord" data-key="' + EventRecord.id + '" >';
                        individualEvent += '<h3>' + EventRecord.name + '</h3>';
                        individualEvent += '<img height="90" width="80" src="' + EventRecord.img + '" />';
                        individualEvent += '<p>Details</p>';
                        individualEvent += '</a></li>';

                        //add the event to the list item and refresh the listview to ensure formatting is retained.
                        $('#listofevents ul').append(individualEvent);
                        $('#listofevents ul:visible').listview('refresh');
                    } //end for loop
                });
            });
        }


        function getEventById(id) {

            db.transaction(function (txs) {
                txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM events where id="' + id + '"', [], function (txs, results) {
                    var len = results.rows.length, i;
                    //loop around each event record in the database
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var EventRecord = results.rows.item(i);
                        //create event list item list item. 
                        var individualEvent = '';
                        individualEvent += '<h3>' + EventRecord.name + '</h3>';
                        individualEvent += '<img height="300" width="300" src="' + EventRecord.img + '" />';
                        individualEvent += '<p>' + EventRecord.location + '</p>';
                        individualEvent += '<p>' + EventRecord.descr + '</p>';
                        individualEvent += ' ';
                        //add the event to the div called #eventSummary (located in the detailinfo sceen)
                        $('#eventSummary').html(individualEvent);
                    } //end for loop
                });
            });
        }


    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- added new database driven menu -->
    <!-- Start of events page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="events" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back" data-transition="slide">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Events Database</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Events near you</p>

            <div data-role="content" id="listofevents">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
                    <!-- events will be inserted here from the database using jquery -->
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>
                <img src="logo_small.png" width="20px" height="20px" alt="Failed" />
        University of Sunderland
            </h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
    <!-- end of database driven menu -->
```

This is what I get when i first load the application: http://i.imgur.com/v7liyjH.jpg

This is what I would like it to display on first run, but only happens after I reload the page: http://i.imgur.com/64yYCG8.jpg

Comment: can you post HTML structure of `#listofevents` and whether are you using `data-filter-reveal="true"`.

Comment: I updated it, with #listofevents

Comment: when do you update the list?

Comment: Well, each time the application starts? I don't understand exactly what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. When do you  call `loadEventRecords()`, on which page event? or on button click..etc and is _events_ page is your first page?

Comment: I call loadEventRecords() in <head>, so each time the application starts. The events page is accessed through a side-menu. The first page (start-up screen) is a navigation map (Google maps script). I added the rest of the database script.

Comment: is _events_ page located in a separate HTML file, e.g events.html? or within the same file (startup screen)?

Comment: I only have a main index.html file with all the code. No additional html files. So yes, within the same file.

Comment: ok, to fix this problem, append `ul` and `li` elements together then call `$("#listofevents ul").listview()`. I guess the problem is that _filterable_ listview should be initiate at once along with `li` elements. try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you 100% is SQLite and not WEBSql or indexedDB.

The query you are using looks like WEBSql statement.

It should display Data Straight away so

The issue is whats calling this function  loadEventRecords()

It wont run unless something calls it to run like a click function. The function is ok but something needs to call it so it can run.

If you just want to run it when the page loads first time then

Try it with a live function and place it in the HEAD, change the #mypage to your page id
The Live methods works with JQM1.3 but has deprecated for later versions so replace the live with on  ----  $( '#mypage' ).on( 'pageshow',function(event){   ---- if you use JQM1.4

```
            $( '#mypage' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event){

        console.log('Loading events records from database into #listofevents ul...');
        db.transaction(function (txs) {
            txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM events', [], function (txs, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length, i;
                //loop around each event record in the database
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    var EventRecord = results.rows.item(i);

                    //create event list item list item. 
                    var individualEvent = '';
                    individualEvent = '<li><a href="#detailinfo" id="aEventRecord" data-key="' +    
                    EventRecord.id + '" >';
                    individualEvent += '<h3>' + EventRecord.name + '</h3>';
                    individualEvent += '<img height="90" width="80" src="' + EventRecord.img + '" 
                     />';
                    individualEvent += '<p>Details</p>';
                    individualEvent += '</a></li>';

                    //add the event to the list item and refresh the listview to ensure 
                    formatting is retained.
                    $('#listofevents ul').append(individualEvent);
                    $('#listofevents ul:visible').listview('refresh');
                } //end for loop
            });
        });
```

});

if that doesn't work put the above at the bottom of page after the HTML tag

and if that doesn't work put the below script without a function statement at the bottom of the Page so it executes last when the whole page loads

```
        console.log('Loading events records from database into #listofevents ul...');
        db.transaction(function (txs) {
            txs.executeSql('SELECT * FROM events', [], function (txs, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length, i;
                //loop around each event record in the database
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    var EventRecord = results.rows.item(i);

                    //create event list item list item. 
                    var individualEvent = '';
                    individualEvent = '<li><a href="#detailinfo" id="aEventRecord" data-key="' +      E                       ventRecord.id + '" >';
                    individualEvent += '<h3>' + EventRecord.name + '</h3>';
                    individualEvent += '<img height="90" width="80" src="' + EventRecord.img + '"                   
                    />';
                    individualEvent += '<p>Details</p>';
                    individualEvent += '</a></li>';

                    //add the event to the list item and refresh the listview to ensure 
                    formatting is retained.
                    $('#listofevents ul').append(individualEvent);
                    $('#listofevents ul:visible').listview('refresh');
                } //end for loop
            });
        });
```

having such scripts were you just want the data to be displayed when the page loads up first time just place them  without using a function at the bottom of your HTML page. That enables the script to run last and thus display the data.

Comment: You are right, it's WebSQL, my mistake. I will try what you suggested.